# admin should delete any stack and user should delete only his own stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

UserA is an admin. UserB and UserC are users.

UserA creates StackA, UserB creates StackB, UserC creates StackC.

UserA can delete any stack.

UserB can delete StackB but it fails to delete StackA and StackC.

UserC can delete StackC but it fails to delete StackA and StackB.

How to implement these permissions in an AWS account with 500 users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is **identifying** which stacks a user is permitted to delete.

There is no concept of a "user's own stack". All resources in AWS are 'owned' by the AWS Account, not a specific user. As long as a user has permission to create a resource in AWS, they can create the resource but the resource then **belongs to the AWS Account**.

One potential way of achieving your goal *might* be to modify IAM permissions such that specified users **can only Create or Delete a stack where the Name of the stack starts with their username**. This could use [IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) to insert the username into the policy.

**Update:** Here is a policy that permits users to Create/Delete stacks, but only where the stack name starts with their username. This means that they can use CloudFormation without impacting other users.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudformation:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:*:*:stack/${aws:username}-*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

For example, if your username is `foo` then it would allow a stack with a name of `foo-bar`.

Comment: IAM Policy does not have access to CloudFormation StackName. Then, I think the best option is to add a stack-level tag and it brings another problem. There is no way to enforce the tag is created and there is no way to set its value to {aws:username}.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a sample policy. I tested it and it works.